# Sencha Touch Fastbook

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Today I have been using the sencha touch framework to build an mobile app. I was very impressed (like many others) with the fastbook app that they showed.
On the blog it says that sencha touch 2.2.0 uses a lot of techniques used in the fastbook app. However when I try their example they do not even come close to the responsiveness of fastbook. The transitions are not so smooth and if you tap their is the delay that most html5 apps have.

My question is can I somewhere find the sourcecode of fastbook? I would love to know how they did the "sidebar" navigation because that responds very "natively".

Comment: Totally agree. Fastbook is way faster than any app using Sencha Touch.  I'm pretty sure they're using a version of Sencha where they removed a lot of things. I'm gonna upgrade my apps to 2.2 to see if there is a real difference with the previous version, especially on Android. About Fastbook, I don't think there will be a release of Fastbook's source code, first for the reason above, and second because Sencha makes money by selling its expertise in knowledge.

Comment: @TDeBailleul + 1 for `Sencha makes money by selling its expertise in knowledge.`

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that there is no way finding the sourcecode of Fastbook. Please read this link:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?255853-Fastbook-Source

It would have been wonderful had they released it. But, incase if you are very specific on implementing slide navigation (Facebook-like) in Sencha Touch. This link will be a great help:

http://innofied.com/simplest-slide-navigation-with-sencha-touch-2-2/

Comment: I find this slide navigation thing buggy, even on iOS.

Comment: Cool thanks for the link. Well what can I say.... they make a big fuzz about telling facebook that they are wrong about HTML5 but do not share their knowledge. I understand that they have to make money but then do not show off like that. This does not help leveraging the HTML 5 community at all.......

Answer (score 1):

Many of the Fastbook techniques (including animationQueue) are in Touch 2.2 and more will be in Touch 2.3 - which is in beta right now. The smooth side bar animation uses multiple iframes, and that's a part of Fastbook that is not (and won't be) in Touch 2.x because the API is not compatible with Touch 2 conventions. We didn't release source because Jacky used an edge build to create the app that used an experimental MVVM. We didn't want people to use this code in their apps because it was undocumented and not production quality.

You can see a much longer description of how Jacky did Fastbook in his SenchaCon 2013 session, which we'll be posting soon.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Looking forward to the SenchaCon session. Would be very helpful for others who have the same question if you post the url here when it is online!

Comment: Hi Michael,
In SenchaCon video [The Building of Fastbook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0NO5rSCfHY&feature=c4-overview&list=UUzWL7ZbdO2WeRxuOqFnXe9A) min 42:20 [Jacky was presenting this code](https://surf-space.com/img/fastbook_code.png).  I am trying to implement it with the regular API (without markup) and cannot find the relevant plugin or config options (_list-driver_, _BufferSize_ etc.)

This is the only plugin I found that might be relative, but I'm not sure how to use it: "Ext.plugin.BufferedList"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

[Sencha Market Sidebar](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-mgd-tab-sidebar)